# move_uploaded_file two or more different image names moves only one

Tags: doctrine, zend-framework3

i am trying to move five different files in one form at the same time but only one image moves. I have five columns for each filename in my database table. The uploaded image names saves in the database column but the only problem is only one file is moved instead of all the files uploaded. Below is code:

```
 //form isValid...
 $post = $form2->getData();

            $imageonetmp = $post["imageone"]["tmp_name"];
            $imageonename = $post["imageone"]["name"];

            $imagetwotmp = $post["imagetwo"]["tmp_name"];
            $imagetwoname = $post["imagetwo"]["name"];

            $imagethreetmp = $post["imagethree"]["tmp_name"];
            $imagethreename = $post["imagethree"]["name"];

            $imagefourtmp = $post["imagefour"]["tmp_name"];
            $imagefourname = $post["imagefour"]["name"];

            $imagefivetmp = $post["imagefive"]["tmp_name"];
            $imagefivename = $post["imagefive"]["name"];

            $filepath = $this->_dir.$imageonename;
            $filepath = $this->_dir.$imagetwoname;
            $filepath = $this->_dir.$imagethreename;
            $filepath = $this->_dir.$imagefourname;
            $filepath = $this->_dir.$imagefivename;


            move_uploaded_file($imageonetmp, $filepath);
            move_uploaded_file($imagetwotmp, $filepath);
            move_uploaded_file($imagethreetmp, $filepath);
            move_uploaded_file($imagefourtmp, $filepath);
            move_uploaded_file ($imagefivetmp, $filepath);

 /*set image names to db here*/
 $entityManager->persist($autos);
            $entityManager->flush();
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same variable name $filepath to write the files.  Meaning you are moving each file but overwriting the previous move.

You should use different variable names e.g. $filepath1, $filepath2, etc...

Or

$filepath = file location...
Move file...

And repeat.